# Add variables of one dataframe to a list of dataframes which contain more rows

Tags: r

I have a df in my environment which I'm using as an overview, it's based on the name of the txt.files I have in my directory. It looks like this.

```
overviewdf.
    V1        Year   Name  V2
    1 xxxx    1000 Name1   a   
    2 xxxx    1001 Name1   b
    3 xxxx    1002 Name1   a
    4 xxxx    1003 Name2   b
    5 xxxx    1004 Name2   b
    6 xxxx    1004 Name2   b
    7 xxxx    1005 Name2   a
    8 xxxx    1006 Name3   a
```

After some preprocessing and text mining, there's one df for each file in my directory, but with a different amount of rows, ranging between 50 and 500 for each sentence.

How can I bind the columns of the overviewdf to their respective df in the list?

so the end result is supposed to look like this.

```
    [[1]]
       V1        Year   Name    V2            V3        V4        V5         V6
  1:   xxxx      1000   Name1   "a"           1          1        NA    0.00000000
  2:   xxxx      1000   Name1   "a"           1          1        NA    0.00000000     
 ---                                              
  352: xxxx      1000   Name1   "a"           1          1        NA    0.00000000
  353: xxxx      1000   Name1   "a"           1          1        NA    0.00000000

[[2]]
            V1       Year   Name    V2            V3        V4        V5         V6
  1:       xxxx      1001   Name1   "a"           1          1        NA    0.00000000
  2:       xxxx      1001   Name1   "a"           1          1        NA    0.00000000     
 ---                                              
  57:      xxxx      1001   Name1   "a"           1          1        NA    0.00000000
  58:      xxxx      1001   Name1   "a"           1          1        NA    0.00000000
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same using gdata package.

```
library(gdata)

df1 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=c("A", "B", "C"))
df2 <- data.frame(c=as.character(1:5), a=5:1)

ma1 <- matrix(as.character(1:4), nrow=2, ncol=2)
ma2 <- matrix(1:6, nrow=3, ncol=2)

cbindX(df1, df2)
cbindX(ma1, ma2)
cbindX(df1, ma1)
cbindX(df1, df2, ma1, ma2)
cbindX(ma1, ma2, df1, df2)
```